# ItemService API - Where's the Query Definition Item?

Tags: itemservice

One of the ways to conduct search via ItemService's RESTful API is through a stored query, as per the docs:

> You use this method to run (“execute”) a query that is stored in a Sitecore item (a “query definition item”.)

So where can I find this "query definition item?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to Sitecore documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/en/the-restful-api-for-the-itemservice.html#UUID-2236f007-67ad-f8df-29dd-03125982edf0_id__Ref390760406) you can run query stored on an item using

> `/item/{id}/query`

url. You must replace the `{id}` part with the item which stores the query, e.g.

> `/sitecore/api/ssc/item/110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9/query`

You can add more parameters, e.g. **pageSize, page, database, includeStandardTemplateFields, fields**:

> `/sitecore/api/ssc/item/110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9/query?pageSize=10&page=5`

Description for all of the can be found in the link above.

There is a `Query Definition` template which you should use to store your query. Just create an item using that template. You can find it in Sitecore with `/sitecore/templates/System/Services/Item Service/Query/Query Definition` path:

[image]

Comment: There it is, thank you! Though I noticed that the field type for the query definition item is a Single Line Text, I assume that we write query scripts the same? e.g. `query:/sitecore/content/**`

Comment: Tbh I'm not sure. Test it and let us know :)

Comment: Confirmed that "query:" is not needed for the Query field. Example below:

/sitecore/content/Site/Home/News//*[@@templatename='News Page']